# What are `CLI client` and `Svnkit client` in Netbeans IDE?

Tags: svn, netbeans

Today start using the new version of Netbeans 7.1.2, I get the below notice as the snapshot.

What are those two `svn client` terms?

[image]

Comment: What did you use to "mark up" the screen shot?  It's nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cli client means that Netbeans will run SVN commands by executing a command line client, or in other words, it will launch a shell (CMD.EXE, bash, etc.) and run the svn command from within that shell.  For this to work, you need to have a svn command line client installed, and be able to run svn client commands (like `svn commit`, `svn update`, `svn info`, etc.)

Svnkit client means that Netbeans will run SVN command by interfacing with a java JAR library that implements a SVN client.  No extra shell is necessary.  For this to work, you need the SVNkit jar file installed, which probably netbeans will do for you if you have the right modules selected.